# Python - Kivy: Change Spinner Options size color

Tags: python, kivy, spinner, dropdown

I'm looking for a way to change the color/ background and size of the options/ buttons that are shown within my spinner widget in kivy. I've read that the dropdown_buttons are defined in the option_cls. My spinners are defined in the .kv file and look like this:

```
Spinner:
   id: select_letter
   text: "Choose a letter"
   values: ('A', 'B', 'C')
   background_normal: 'graphics/buttons/dropdown_green.png'
   background_down: 'graphics/buttons/dropdown_blue.png'
   on_text:
      root.set_values()
```

How can I change the properties of the spinner options while keeping my spinner defined in kivy? Is there a way to directly change the size and background of it in the kv? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444763/kivy-how-to-change-spinner-button-colour-and-size)

Comment: yes I did, but I don‘t know how I can adapt that solution to my .kv file since it‘s all defined in python.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a way to change the color/ background and size of the options/ buttons that are shown within my spinner widget in kivy.

The below code snippet worked for me

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory


 
<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>:
    background_color: [0, 0, 1, 1]    # blue colour
    background_down: ''
    
 
<MyThing>:
    Spinner:
        id: select_letter
        text: "Choose a letter"
        values: ('A', 'B', 'C')
        background_normal: 'graphics/buttons/dropdown_green.png'
        background_down: 'graphics/buttons/dropdown_blue.png'
        option_cls: Factory.get("MySpinnerOption")
        on_text:
            root.set_values()
```

Reference: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Styling-a-Spinner-and-SpinnerOption-in-KV

Answer (score 0):

Since there you provide no actual code, I can't test it, but you can try to change the `option_cls` of the `Spinner` you use, with one that you modified.

```py
Spinner:
   id: select_letter
   text: "Choose a letter"
   values: ('A', 'B', 'C')
   background_normal: 'graphics/buttons/dropdown_green.png'
   background_down: 'graphics/buttons/dropdown_blue.png'
   option_cls: MySpinnerOption
   on_text:
      root.set_values()

<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>:
    background_color: [0, 0, 1, 1]    # blue colour
```